# Calendar with multiple date selection for Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I need to show a calendar and let the user pick multiple dates - e.g. 1/2/2017, 1/3/2017, 1/4/2017. That is, not a range, but multiple dates.

In Angular 1.x, I used the [gm.datepickerMultiSelect](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) directive on top of UI Bootstrap to accomplish this.

I am not able to find such solution for Angular 2+, either using `ng-bootstrap` or `PrimeNg` or some other library. Any points will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this tool from a similar post: https://github.com/xtianus79/multiple-date-picker-a2

Can you try that out and see if it fits your needs?

Comment: I would only add that this link has a version that is for all new versions of angular. and it is the npm package... https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-date-picker-angular

Comment: @user11081980 .. may be this is what you are looking for. -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-date-range-picker