# Multiple date selection ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Is their a way to activate multi-select in datepicker of ngx-bootstrap? I found a hack [here](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) but this is built using `angularjs` but I'm currently working on `Angular 2`. Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one

https://github.com/xtianus79/multiple-date-picker-angular

It has a decent documentation as well

Comment: i cant because other components are also using the same plugin, changing it will implact all components

Comment: adding the npm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246531/calendar-with-multiple-date-selection-for-angular-2?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Problem with adding multiselect is adding multi unselect,
you can dig into Datepicker implementation

by overriding https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-container.component.ts#L59-L64

implementation and modifying day click handler, you can get any behavior you want, in nearest time we will be adding in depth docs on how to customize datepickers